# webview как передать ссылку на pdf в AndroidPdfViewer

Tags: android, webview

есть webview он открывает html страницу со списком pdf файлов и есть AndroidPdfViewer в таком виде:

```
PDFView pdfView = (PDFView) v.findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
InputStream input = new URL("").openStream();
pdfView.fromStream(input).load();
```

вопрос: как передать ссылку в AndroidPdfViewer при нажатии на pdf файл?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

решение:

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if (url.endsWith("pdf")) {
                    PDFView receiptView = (PDFView) v.findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
                    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                        @SuppressLint("WrongThread")
                        @Override
                        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                            try {
                                InputStream input = new URL(url).openStream();
                                receiptView.fromStream(input).load();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            return null;
                        }
                    }.execute();
                    return true;

                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```